# F# getting file contents without providing fulll path

Tags: path, f#

I'm doing a small F# program where I am reading a markdown file, and store it as a string:

```
open System.IO
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let text = File.ReadAllText("/home/ask/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/File.md")
    printfn "%s" text
    
    0
```

It works like it is here, where I provide the full path. But I need to use a relative path, since I need to put this on a server at some point.

My `Program.fs` and `File.md` is in the same directory, So i've tried all these paths, that have'nt worked.

```
- File.md
- /File.md
- ~/File.md
```

NOthing works. How do I provide the correct path?

I'm running ubuntu

**EDIT**

I accidentally wrote "txt" as the extension for some of my examples above. This is now corrected.

The directory that I am working in looks like this:

```
├── ConsoleApp1
│   ├── bin
│   ├── ConsoleApp1.fsproj
│   ├── File.md
│   ├── obj
│   └── Program.fs
└── ConsoleApp1.sln
```

`Program.fs` is the F# file, with my code in. `File.md` is the file I want to read

Comment: What is File.md? Relative to what? Is your intention to place File.txt along with the executable, or somewhere relative to the current directory? I'm not familiar with Linux, but on Windows these are different things, though most developers don't understand that.

Comment: I added an edit, which should clear things up

Comment: There is a bin folder there, and your executable is somewhere below that, perhaps directly in bin, perhaps in a folder within bin. I assume the program's current folder will be the same as the executable's folder. That means you will likely get to your file using "../File.md" or "../../File.md" or maybe even "../../../File.md" as path.

Comment: The problem might still be that a path like "../File.md" is relative to the current directory, and not relative to the executable. Most developers aren't aware of the difference, because usually the two will be the same path (at least in Windows). Then it fails at some point in the future, usually when a user of the software tries to start it in some manner the developer didn't account for.

Comment: gr8, this works.Rigtigt mange tak Bent

Comment: Just one more tip: If your intention is to have File.md deployed along with the executable, then you should do two things. First is that File.md should be CopyToOutputDirectory so that (a copy of) it ends up alongside the executable. (Actually I should have mentioned this earlier, because then you could have used just "File.md" in any case.) Second is that instead of using a relative path like I've shown, you should find the path of the executable's directory, and combine that with the file name. This way the program will find the file irrespective of what the current directory is.

Answer (score 1):

One of the more useful utilities is `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` so you can reference things like files relative to the source file's directory. So just a simple `Path.Join` will get you the file.

```
let mdPath = Path.Join(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__, "File.md")
```